# Adjusting User Context with TreeStoreBuilder

Tags: rally, code-rally

I've been able to create a grid and basic filtering to narrow down iterations etc. Ideally I would like to run this via html/confluence so ideally I need to have the filtering set so that I can filter on parent as well as project. Testing this in the Rally dashboard, the way I have it still only working within project I'm sitting in. How do I make my filtering work so that where I'm at project wise in Rally doesn't matter or if I use my api key.

Thanks!
Mark

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
     models: ['userstory'],
      autoLoad: true,
      enableHierarchy: true,
      filters: [{property: 'Iteration.Name',
                 operator : '=',
                 value : 'March'},
                {property: 'Project.Parent.Name',
                 operator : '=',
                 value : 'Synergy'},
                {property: 'Project.Name',
                 operator : '=',
                 value : 'Condor'}
            ]
  }).then({
      success: function(store) {
         Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
                items: [{
                 xtype: 'rallytreegrid',
                 columnCfgs: [
                     'DisplayColor',
                     'Name',
                     'ScheduleState',
                     'Blocked',
                     'TaskEstimateTotal',
                     'TaskRemainingTotal',
                     'Owner',
                     'Notes'
                 ],
                 store: store
             }],
             renderTo: Ext.getBody()
         });
     }
 });
```

Comment: Are you trying to read items across your entire workspace? So, all projects?  Or just a specific subset?  Or a specific branch of the project tree?

Comment: I'd like to be able to have the wiki get data from all projects within the workspace... The way I have things organized is Workspace/Parent Project A/Project A,B,C  ... ParentProjectB/Project A,B,C... To test this out I was trying to do this on my Rally Dashboard/HTML before trying to migrate it over to the Confluence wiki... My goal is to have a story task list/burn down chart/release chart for each subproject on 1 wiki page. Thanks! Mark

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass a context to your store:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/data_stores-section-scoping

All projects:

```
{ project: null, workspace: '/workspace/12345'}
```

Specific project:

```
{ project: '/project/12345', projectScopeDown: false, projectScopeUp: false }
```

Project hierarchy:

```
    { project: '/project/12345', projectScopeDown: true, projectScopeUp: false }
```

Or if you are trying to get data from multiple projects not in a tree you can always create a filter in the store on Project like you're doing above.  Note that you'll need to make sure all those projects are actually in scope based on your context to get any results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input! I'm struggling where to actually add this in the code and getting to work like I would like... My structure is WS/ProjectA/subprojA, subprojB, ProjectB/subprojA, B etc.. I'm trying such that it doesn't matter where I'm sitting project wise I can force the source/tree to the project/subproject I want... Ideally I want to take this to a wiki where I can have several of these instance pointing to different projects.  Thanks for the help!! Mark

Comment: it just gets passed as the context parameter in the config object passed to the tree store builder